# Clear the input data after submit using typehead

Tags: reactjs

My Typeahead component:

```
<Typeahead
              ref="SubjectTypeahead"
              placeholder="Search Subjects"
              onChange={this.onSearchSubjects}
              options={subjectNames}/>
```

My onChange function:

```
  onSearchSubjects = (values) => {
    if (values.length > 0) {
      this.refs.SubjectTypeahead.getInstance().clear()
      this.props.onSearchSubjects(values[0])
    }
  }
```

When selecting a value form the typeahead, my onChange method gets called, but the value selected doesn't get cleared.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is now solved using the

Public Methods
To access the component's public methods, add a ref to your typeahead instance and access the ref from a given handler:

```
<div>
  <Typeahead
    ...
    ref={(typeahead) => this.typeahead = typeahead}
  />
  <button onClick={() => this.typeahead.getInstance().clear()}>
    Clear Typeahead
  </button>
</div>
```

Note that you must use getInstance to get the typeahead instance.

```
blur()
```

Provides a programmatic way to blur the input.

```
clear()
```

Provides a programmatic way to reset the component. Calling the method will clear both text and selection(s).

```
focus()
```

Provides a programmatic way to focus the input.

```
getInput()
```

Provides access to the component's input node.